# Quantifiers and equivalent expressions

Tags: real-analysis, logic, predicate-logic

I've seen continuity in R defined in the two following ways. Namely

$$\forall c \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists \delta>0, ((x\in X \land |c-x|<\delta) \implies |f(c)-f(x)| < \epsilon) $$

$$\forall c \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists \delta>0, \forall x\in X (|c-x|<\delta \implies |f(c)-f(x)| < \epsilon) $$

Thus (letting $A = |c-x|<\delta$ and $ B= |f(c)-f(x)| < \epsilon$) it must be that for statements $A,B$, the following are equivalent.

$$\forall x \in X,(A\implies B) $$ $$(x \in X \land A) \implies B$$

I'd like to prove this formally, but I'm not sure how. I tried calling both $x\in X$ and $\forall x \in X$ statement $C$, and making a truth table. I found that 
$$C \land (A\implies B) \equiv (C \land A) \implies B$$ iff $C$ is true. I'm quite confused; do quantifiers like  $\forall x \in X$ even have truth values?

Comment: Quantifiers do not have truth values. I think in the second statement the brackets have been omitted and that is the only difference (but the statement is to be interpreted in the same way). It looks like your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are not quantified correctly?

Comment: @any the 2nd definition was from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity. The first was Elementary Analysis The Theory of Calculus, Ross, 2e page 124.

Comment: Notice: It is $\ldots\forall\varepsilon{>}0~\exists \delta{>}0\dots$  Note also the difference between *continuity* and *uniform continuity*.

Comment: @Evan Rosica So it should be for all epsilon there exists delta? Unless  this is special type of continuity (eg uniform)?

Comment: @Any yes, it should be $\forall \epsilon>0,  \exists \delta>0 $. good catch . That said it shouldn't affect the question. That was just context. In uniform continuity the $\forall c \in X$ would move after the $\exists \delta $

Comment: Sure. You may find it useful to read the Wikipedia entry on Prenex Normal Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, quantifiers do not have truth values, on their own.   However a restricted quantifier has equivalent forms, and we can use universal generalisation.

$$\begin{align}(\forall x\in X) (A(x)\,\to\, B(x)) ~&\iff (\forall x)\Big(x\in X\to\big(A(x)\to B(x)\big)\Big) \\[1ex] ~&\iff (\forall x)\big((x\in X\,\wedge\, A(x))\,\to\, B(x)\big)\\[1ex] &\;\implies (x_1\in X\,\wedge\, A(x_1))\;\to\; B(x_1)\end{align}$$

So the formal definition is: $~\forall c {\in} X~ \forall \varepsilon {>} 0 ~ \exists \delta{>}0 ~ \forall x{\in} X ~\big(\lvert c-x\rvert<\delta ~\to~ \lvert f(c)-f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon\big)~$ where all variables are bound.

Infering a generalised form: $\forall c {\in} X~ \forall \varepsilon {>} 0 ~ \exists \delta{>}0 ~ \big(\big(x\in X~\wedge~\lvert c-x\rvert<\delta\big) ~\to~ \lvert f(c)-f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon\big)$ where the arbitrary variable, $x$, is free.

---

Note:

- The first form is the stronger *uniform continuity*, and states that there exists a $\delta$ for *all* $x$, which satisfies the predicate.
- The second form is weaker *continuity*; it states that for each arbitrary value, $x$, there is some $\delta$ value that satisfies the predicate.

Comment: The first form is not uniform continuity. The first form was Theorem 17.2 from Ross. Uniform continuity is Defn 19.1 from Ross, and states: $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x,y\in S |x-y| < \delta \implies |(f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon $$

Comment: The difference between the first definition I gave in my original post and  the definition of uniform continuity above is that the $\forall c$ moves after the $\delta$ (indicating $\delta$ no longer depends on $c$), and Ross renames $c=y$, since the roles of $x,y$ are symmetric.